# Showcasing Flex - Tour de Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, spam

I ran across [Tour de Flex](http://flex.org/tour) a couple days ago. It's a demo that showcases all the Flex controls, with cross-references to source and references. It's a great way to get an idea of the resources available, and how to use them.

Not a question, but a useful resource since I've seen a number of Flex/Actionscript questions here.

(Note that I've preflagged all the no-credit tags I can think of already. Pile on more if you can think of any.)

Comment: Tagging a question 'community-wiki' does not make it a community wiki question.

Answer (score 2):

Q: When is a question not a question?

---

A: When it is rhetorical.

It think it would be best to make this question answerable rather than try to avoid taking credit.  For instance, I would have asked something like:

> What are some good resources for understanding Flex controls?

That would have set up the body of your "question" to be an acceptable answer.

In addition, you might have found other people would have contributed other resources that they've found.  As it stands, this question does not invite further answers and has the appearance of spam.  Just so you know.

Comment: Well said. Also, he could've gotten a self-learner badge out of it ^_^